# How can we pass UDTT to a db2 procedure from nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, db2

I am using ibm_db node module for connecting to DB2 from my nodeJS solution. I have a stored procedure that accepts a UDTT as an input. Could someone please share an example of how to pass UDTT to SP from nodeJS?

Comment: no, I am closing the connection after making an SP call.

Comment: What's UDTT? What's UDTT?

Comment: User Defined Table Types. They are used if I want to pass multiple rows to the SP at once. @mustaccio

Comment: Are you using Oracle syntax+compatibility mode,  or are you using Db2 typed-tables?  It would help if you EDIT your question to show an example of your structured type, and its transform groups. In Db2 CLI SQLBindParameter(), as used by `ibm_db` for node.js, the type of a stored-procedure parameter has to map on to a ctype .